# Hibernate/SpringData @OneToMany is not returning a list with new record saved

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

There are two classes.

Order

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
@Getter
List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

OrderItem
Order order;
etc.

If you save a new orderItem directly in the database, then have Order object still floating around, how do you refresh the order object in a way that when you call getOrderItems, the new OrderItem you saved is also going to be in the list?

Assume that because of the way the app is - you can't add the new OrderItem to the order list and save on the order - you have to save the orderItem directly, then refresh the order somehow so that the list of OrderItems on order contains the new record.

Thank you!

Comment: how is your relationship defined, unidirectional or bidirectional

Comment: There is one "orders" table, and the "order_items" table has "order_id" that's the only reference. So there is a one to many relationship between order and order_items.